# Convert text in listview widgets to json in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, jsonparser

I have a dynamically created listview where all the items were created on a button click and I need to convert all the listview items (which were widgets of TextFields) in json format and save it in database eventually.

[image]

There will be a floating action button to save which is not in the above picture. In the above scenario, I wanted to save the data of all the Course topics entered in the listview widgets as follows.

```
{"name": "OOPS", "name": "OOPS", "name": "OOPS",...}
```

Any suggestions to achieve this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain to me more? I can't understand.

Comment: Here one listview and when user click on Add button then one item will add into ListView with TextField.Do you want all data of listview which added by the user?

Comment: Scenario:

I've a main textfield which is "Course Name". And below it is a listview widget in which it's elements gets added by clicking on the "+" button at the end of the "Course Name". After adding multiple courses, there will be a floating action button to save all the courses.

In the above scenario, when I click on floating action button, I wanted to save all the lessons as follows

{name: "OOPS", name: "OOPS", name: "OOPS"....}